# Increase string array value +1?

Tags: c#, windows, arrays, forms

**How would I increase the value of this array +1?**

I have some code but its not getting +1 the value of that array.

By +1 I mean the array value 1 above that one, so if my array contains the words: Hi, Hey Hello, instead of it displaying Hi I want it so display Hey.

**Heres the code I have but its not moving it +1 up:**

```
string[] u = getBetweenAll(vid, "</id><published>", "</published><updated>");
                for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
                {

                    string input = u[i] + 1;
                    int index = input.IndexOf("T");
                    if (index > 0)
                        input = input.Substring(0, index);
                    listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add(input);
                }
```

Comment: So you have a string array that contains three elements, right? {"Hi", "Hey", "Hello"}. And you want to move every elements "up", right? Then the last element is now the first one? Is that what you want to get?

Comment: if you just want to get the element "to the right" of the one you're currently pointing at, your `string input = u[i] + 1;` should be `string input = u[i + 1];`, but you need to check that you're not going beyond the last element or you'll get a IndexOutOfRangeException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean:

```
string input = u[i + 1];
```

Comment: @EdwinTorres And what about the last element?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan good point. there needs to be a check for that

Answer (score 0):

```
 string input = u[i + 1];
```

you need to increment the indexer